# Kotlin getValue for String containing word/s ignoring case Upper or Lower and spaceing

Tags: regex, list, kotlin

I have generated a list from file.

The list contains a list that looks this below

(redTomatoes, 47.50)
(greenapple, 23.75)
(yellowBananas, 17)

and so forth

```
        var value = versionsList.getValue("banana")
        println("This is the value $value")
```

The above code won't retrun the value because it doesn't match exactly. I can't add ignoreCase or contains with .getValue

Is it possible to search for a String containing a word while ignoring case, spacing?

Do I need to create some sort of loop to test all possible combinations to get value?

Thanks

Comment: >  "while ignoring case, spacing?" So you might also have an input as "yellow Bananas" and not just "yellowBananas"?

Comment: You are saying that you have a list, but I assume you mean that you have a map?

Comment: That is correct, it could be yellow banana instead of yellowbanana. And yes, it is a map.

Comment: Can you modify the loading code to make all of the inputs lower case without spaces?

Comment: So you are suggesting that I modify the the value, I'm searching for to be one case and to remove spaces? I would also have to modify the list to be of one case.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to search for a String containing a word while ignoring case, spacing?

It *is* possible, but it is not something that can be done without iterating over all elements.

> Do I need to create some sort of loop to test all possible combinations to get value?

So yes, a loop of some sort is needed, but testing all possible combinations is a bit extreme. A preferable way would have been to use `.toLowerCase()` on any String before putting it into the map, even tough it would not entirely remove the ambiguity of the format of the keys. But even without such altering of the input, it can be solved.

#### A Proposed Solution

Given the input such as

```
val fruits: Map<String, Double> = mapOf(
                "redTomatoes" to 47.50,
                "greenapple" to 23.75,
                "yellowBananas" to 17.0
        )
```

and the assumption that the data cannot be modified before inserting to the map, I propose that we convert them into a more common format when retrieving a value from the map. Since the irregularities is capital letters and spaces between words, we need to transform all keys and inputs to a common format without spaces and in lower case. Transforming a String can conveniently be written as an extension function.

`fun String.toLowerCaseWithoutWhiteSpace() = this.toLowerCase().replace(Regex("\\s+"), "")`

But as we cannot use `.getValue()` on our map for this, we need to write a custom function for that.

```
fun <T> Map<String, T>.getLike(key: String): T?
{
    val transformed = key.toLowerCaseWithoutWhiteSpace()
    return this
            .asSequence()
            // Change the keys in the map so they are also lower case and without whitespace
            .map { it.key.toLowerCaseWithoutWhiteSpace() to it.value}
            // Take the first entry where the key matches
            .firstOrNull { (keyInMap, _) ->
                keyInMap == transformed
            }
            // Return the value from the entry
            ?.second
}
```

And we can then use the following to access the right values

```
fruits.getLike("yellow bananas")
fruits.getLike("green apple")
fruits.getLike("red tomatoes")
```

This does of course come with a performance penalty, accessing the right value will have a time complexity of O(N) instead of O(1). This might be okay for a smaller map, but if there will be a lot of elements in your map, you might consider processing the elements before inserting them in the map, or if it is not possible, creating a new map were all keys have been converted as I have done above.